# How to get number of iterations in nested foreach JSTL

Tags: foreach, nested, jstl

I have a TreeMap with

```
<c:if test="${!empty viewObjects}">
    <table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <c:forEach items="${viewObjects}" var="relations">
        <c:forEach items="${relations.value}" var="role" varStatus="status">
            <c:set var="subcount" value="${status.count + 1 }"/>
            <tr class="color<c:out value="${subcount%2}"/>">
                <td>${relations.key}</td>
                <td>${role.name}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

how can i have subcount increase with only +1 for every iteration within the nested foreach?
From what I experience "status" starts over when the first foreach iterates, so that also affects the subcount, and I will not get the total iterations.

Answer (score 4):

You would do it the same way as you would do in Java: by using a counter variable initialized outside of the outermost loop:

```
int counter = 0;
for (...) {
    for (...) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

So in JSTL, it would become

```
<c:set var="counter" value="0"/>
<c:forEach ...>
    <c:forEach ...>
        <c:set var="counter" value="${counter + 1}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```